# Jupyter Notebook is stuck on "Loading..."

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, pymongo

So I am trying to run this pymongo app through jupyter notebook and all it does is give me a "Loading..." output and then the kernel goes idle... when I just print the "df", it gives me the data so I know that it is working data-wise. I have tried restarting the kernel; deleting the output, restarting the kernel, and reinputting the input; Restarting and clearing output - and all do not seem to have any effect. I am thinking it may have something to do with my inputted data but I am not sure what exactly...

This is the .ipynb:

```
from jupyter_plotly_dash import JupyterDash
import dash
import dash_leaflet as dl
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pymongo import MongoClient
#### FIX ME #####
# change animal_shelter and AnimalShelter to match your CRUD Python module file name and class name
from AAC import AnimalShelter

###########################
# Data Manipulation / Model
###########################
# FIX ME update with your username and password and CRUD Python module name
username = "aacuser"
password = "monogoadmin"
shelter = AnimalShelter(username, password)
# class read method must support return of cursor object and accept projection json input
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.read({}))

#########################
# Dashboard Layout / View
#########################
app = JupyterDash('Dash DataTable Only')

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='hidden-div', style={'display':'none'}),
    html.Center(html.B(html.H1('SNHU CS-340 Dashboard'))),
    html.Hr(),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-interactivity',
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        #FIXME: Set up the features for your interactive data table to make it user-friendly for your client
        editable=False,
        filter_action="native",
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode="multi",
        column_selectable=False,
        row_selectable=False,
        row_deletable=False,
        selected_columns=[],
        selected_rows=[],
        page_action="native",
        page_current= 0,
        page_size= 10,
    ),
    html.Br(),
     html.Hr(),
     
])


app
```

This is the .py file:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
    """CRUD operations for Animal collection in Mongodatabase"""
    #Initializes MongoClient
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:38574', username='aacuser', password='mongoadmin', authSource='AAC', authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1')
        self.database = self.client['AAC']  
    #Implement create method
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            return self.database.animals.insert_one(data)
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")
    #Implement read method
    def read(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            return self.database.animals.find(data)
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to read, because data parameter is empty")
    #Implement update method
    def update(self, data):
        if find is not None:
            return self.database.animals.update_one(data)
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to update, because data parameter is empty")
    #Implement delete method
    def delete(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            return self.database.animals.delete_one(data)
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to delete, because data parameter is empty")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

[Here is the requested screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f00Tv.png)

I also wanted to note that I cleared cache and cookies and this had no effect.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of that "Loading..."? Where does it show up?

Comment: I just linked in the screenshot for review. Thank you for the response!

Comment: The "Loading..." just shows up as the output.

Comment: It looks like it is a problem with the data table because the header set up loads just fine...

Comment: Could this be a problem with the to_dict() function?

Comment: Hmm I am unfamiliar with pymongo, but maybe you can try to show it outside Jupyter Notebook to figure out whether Jupyter is the issue or your app.